# How should I indent nested case expressions?

Tags: haskell, indentation

How to indent correctly a nested case expression in haskell that would act like a nested loop in imperative programming ?

```
f x y = case x of
     1 -> case y of 
          1 -> 
          2 -> 
          ...        
     2 -> case y of 
       ...
```

The compiler gives me an indentation error at the start of the second x case, so i'm guessing it doesn't understand that the first x case is over

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code seems ok. Haskell has a very simple rule of Indenation as explained in wikibooks:

> Code which is part of some expression should be indented further in
>   than the beginning of that expression.

This works for me:

```
f x y = case x of
     1 -> case y of 
       1 -> undefined
       2 -> undefined
     2 -> case y of
       1 -> undefined
```

You may want to check your editor to see if it is doing proper indentation. As @Tarmil suggested, always use spaces for indentation. More details on that [here.](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/Tabs)

Comment: "You may want to check your editor to see if is doing proper indentation." -> In particular you may want to check if it uses tabs. I recommend you configure it to only use spaces for Haskell.

Comment: @Tarmil or use `{ ; }` to eliminate ambiguity. It might actually improve readability as well, in such cases.

Comment: It was indeed a tabulation problem, I replaced them by spaces and it worked with the exact same indentation

Answer (score 8):

Not directly an answer, but could maybe helpful nevertheless:

In this particular case, you could also write:

```
f 1 1 = ...
f 1 2 = ...
f 2 2 = ...
```

or, as a case expression:

```
f x y = case (x, y) of
   (1,1) -> ...
   (1,2) -> ...
   (2,1) -> ...
```

Comment: Very helpful because more readable. Java is damaging my brain, I feel stupid to have come up with this ugly solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was due to that I was using tabs for identation. When I indentated the code with spaces, it worked!